# What range should I use for floating point values?

Tags: floating-point

I'm aware of the implementation and limitations of floating point values - I've read the paper you're probably about to link me to - but I can't figure out what range I should use for floating point values.

I want to represent a value in a real, finite range. Conceptually, -1 to 1. I could just use floating point values -1 to 1, but then am I wasting the mantissa bits?

There was [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10907266/when-i-use-floating-point-numbers-do-i-lose-precision-if-i-limit-the-range) but there wasn't really a conclusive answer.

Comment: No, you'd be "wasting" exponent bits; precision is not affected by limiting the range.  But that's probably not a big problem, unless you have some weird constraints.

Comment: What precision do you need in that range?

Comment: I guess the 53 bits of the significand are enough, so I'm sure you're going to say if that's enough it's enough, but what is the real _solution_ to this question - it's bugging me!

Comment: @user1941301: I don't know; what's the problem?  Are you concerned that you're effectively halving your dynamic range? (note, that's not the same as precision...)  If you need to represent numbers smaller than 1e-308, then I guess it's a problem...

Comment: My intuition tells me that making your calculations more convoluted in order to use a "more optimum" range would net you a maximum of one bit of precision. You'd have to be pretty damn (un)lucky to have a calculation whose result hinges on having either 52 or 53 bits of precision.

Comment: I guess I'm concerned that by setting an arbitrary range I am arbitrarily limiting the resolution of the quantisation of this value. Good programs don't set arbitrary limits beyond those in the underlying system, and good programs don't waste resources like bits in floats. And I want to write a good program.

Comment: @user1941301: But you're not limiting the resolution, only the range.  And that's only a problem if it's a problem!

Comment: The range is fixed by the application domain, so I'm not limiting that. I'm concerned about limiting the number of representable values within the range when using an IEEE double. I'm worried that if I quantise as float values -1,1 are there less representable values in there compared to -256,256.

Comment: @user1941301: Apologies, I meant *dynamic* range. A hypothetical representation with an unsigned exponent would only buy you anything for numbers in the range -1e-308 to +1e-308.  For anything outside that range, there would be no benefit.

Comment: @user1941301: Oh, unless you're talking about trading that exponent bit for a mantissa bit, and having a 54-bit mantissa field?  In which case, yes, you'd buy yourself 1 bit of precision across your entire range.  But at the expense of not being able to do any of the calculations in floating-point hardware (plus no native compiler support!).

Comment: Ok, thing it's likely not worth any more time thinking about it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The primary point of floating point is that the point floats.

That means you have the same relative precision in the vicinity of 1 that you do in the vicinity of 256. For the vast majority of applications, there is no point in scaling your numbers to be in one range or another.

In very specific, finicky situations, there can be reasons to scale.

One is if you need a huge dynamic range. If your numbers are in [-1, +1], then your smallest non-zero number will be 2<sup>-1074</sup>, in IEEE 754 64-bit binary. However, it will have reduced precision. The smallest number with full precision will be 2<sup>-1022</sup>. That is plenty for anything normal. If 1 corresponds to any observable physical phenomenon (e.g., the mass of the observable universe), then 2<sup>-1022</sup> is below any observable threshold (it is about 10<sup>-223</sup> times the mass of an electron). There is simply no point in calculating anything that small for physical things—It is generally of interest only to mathematicians. If you have some special mathematical application you are working, then perhaps you could get some benefit from changing your scale from [-1, +1] to something larger, like [-2<sup>1023</sup>, +2<sup>1023</sup>]. (But leave yourself some room for arithmetic without overflow.)

Another is in a situation where the relative error matters and the floating-point precision is barely enough for your needs. The relative error in representing numbers around 1.1 is greater than the relative error in representing numbers around .9 or 1.9. This is due to the way numbers are represented in floating point, with a significand that is linear (rather than logarithmic) within each exponent range. So the smallest increments available around 1.1 are the same as the increments available around 1.9, but they are a smaller portion of 1.9 than they are of 1.1. This will not matter in virtually all uses of floating-point; it tends to arise only in limited situations such as math libraries where very careful evaluations of errors must be made in order to ensure quality software.

Summary: Do not worry about range. Let your floating point float.